# How to pass data from one input into another in Gravity Forms?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, auto-populate

There are two inputs in one form, one is Name, second is read-only - Signature. I need to pass whatever user types in first input to another and display same value on-the-run.

Can  I do this via jQuery? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can update using jQuery

```
jQuery('input[name="SIGNATURE_FIELD_NAME"]').val('input[name="NAME_FIELD_NAME"]');
```

Please replace SIGNATURE_FIELD_NAME by your signature field name and NAME_FIELD_NAME by your name field name

Answer (score 0):

this was the final solution, inputs selected by names, as GF doesn't allow to set up unique ID's

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input[name="input_1"]').keyup(function () { 
        $('input[name="input_2"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```